# Arrow pointing to edge of marker independently from markers size

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

This is goes in the same direction as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14594786/fancyarrowpatch-to-edge-of-marker-with-known-size).

I want to point an arrow from one scatter point to another, so that the arrow head lies next to edge of the marker. Like in the following example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter([0,1],[0,1], s=300)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch(posA=(0,0), posB=(1,1), arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=20, shrinkA=7, shrinkB=7)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Here I chose the values of `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` manually so that the arrow head is lying very close from the edge of the target scatter point. However, I would have to change those values if I change the size of the markers.

My question is: Knowing the size of the markers (kwarg `s` in ax.scatter), how can chose `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` so that the arrow lies close from the marker's edge?

I know that `s` is measured in p^2 where p is a typographic point. So that the radius of the marker is `sqrt(s / pi)`. If `shrinkA` and `shrinkB` are measured in the same typographic points, we could just do `shrinkB=radius` where `radius` is the radius of the marker.

For s==300 this makes sense as the radius is close to 9.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `shrinkA`/`shrinkB` arguments of `FancyArrowPatch` expect their argument in units of points. Points is also the unit of linewidth or markersize. For a scatter plot, the size argument `s` is the square of the markersize.

So given the `size` of the scatter plot, `s=size`, the `shrink` is calculated by taking the squareroot and dividing by 2 (because you want to shrink the arrow by the radius, not the diameter).

```
shrink = math.sqrt(size)/2.
```

Example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import math

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
size = 1000
radius = math.sqrt(size)/2.
points = ax.scatter([0,1], [0,1], s=size)
arrow = mpl.patches.FancyArrowPatch(posA=(0,0), posB=(1,1), 
                                    arrowstyle='-|>', mutation_scale=20, 
                                    shrinkA=radius, shrinkB=radius)
ax.add_patch(arrow)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So markersize is the length between the two furthermost points in the marker (in the case of the circle, the diameter)?

Comment: That would be true for a circle, yes. For other markers, e.g. if you took `"$.$"`, it cannot be determined that easily.